# Replace the code block button with a multi-line quote button

Tags: feature-request, markdown

The text editor on this site has a code block button. There are very few reasons for posting code on a site about literature--I suppose it might be warranted for answers to questions about the [digital humanities](http://www.digitalhumanities.org/dhq/vol/11/2/000317/000317.html), but that would be about it.

At the moment, code blocks are being used relatively frequently as a substitute for multiline quotes when people quote poetry. [Here's one example of this](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/4888/revisions). This should be discouraged, because it makes the site inaccessible to people using screenreaders. But posting multiline quotes for poetry is unintuitive, and even if you know how to do it, it can take a while to add the double spaces to the end of each line.

Could we replace the code button in the editor with a button for multiline quotes?

Comment: I agree that `<code>` should not be used for blockquotes, but could you explain how `<code>` makes content inaccessible to screenreaders?